# Graph Matrix Labeling

Tags: c++, matrix, graph

I am new to graphs and vectors, I am trying to label the points on the graph A, B, C, etc.

```
class GraphMatrix
{
    private:
        int n;
        int **adj;
        bool *visited;

        vector <string> label;

    public:
        GraphMatrix(const vector<string>&labels)
        {
            this->n = n;
            visited = new bool [n];
            adj = new int* [n];

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                adj[i] = new int [n];

                for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    adj[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        bool add_edge(const string &origin, const string &destin)
        {

            int nodes;

            vector<string>::iterator opos, dpos;
        opos = std::find(label.begin(), label.end(), origin);
        dpos = std::find(label.begin(), label.end(), destin);


            if (opos == label.end() || dpos == label.end()) return false;

            opos-label.begin();

        }
            /*

            */


        void List()
        {
            int i,j, nodes;




            for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    cout << adj[i][j] << "  ";
                }

                cout<<endl;

                cout << "\nMatrix Graph\n" << endl;


                for(int i = 0; i < nodes; i++)
                {
                     cout << label[i] << "  ";
                }

                cout << '\n';


                for(int i = 0; i < nodes; i++)
                    {
                      cout << label[i] << "\n";
                    }

                 // assign labels to each node
               // for ( int i = 1; i < nodes; i++ )
                //{
                  //  label [ i ] = label [ i - 1 ] + 1;
                //}       

            }
        }
};


int main()
{
    string  origin, destin;
    int nodes, max_edges;

    //char label[] =  {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'};
    //label [ 0 ] = 'A';

    vector<string> label;

    cout << "How many points? ";
    cin >> nodes;

       cout << "Label the points: \n";
                for(int i = 0; i < nodes; i++ )
                {
                    cout << "Enter label for point # " << i << " ";
                    cin >> label[i];
                }  


    GraphMatrix graph(label);

    max_edges = nodes * (nodes - 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < max_edges; i++)
        {
            cout << "Define edges between two points (q q to exit): ";

            cin >> origin >> destin;

            if((origin == "q") && (destin == "q"))
            {
                break;
            }

            graph.add_edge(origin, destin);
        }

    graph.List();

    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

My output is :

```
How many points? 5
Label the points: 
Enter label for point # 0 A
```

And then it stops.

```
I am trying to get a graph that looks like this:

  A  B  C  D  E
A 0  1  0  1  1
B 0  0  1  0  1
C 1  0  0  0  0
D 0  0  1  0  0
E 0  1  0  0  0
```

Can anyone please help? I had the graph printing fine without labeling. Then I tried adding vectors which is totally new to me, now I can't get it to work.

Comment: `std::vector<string> label` is not initialized but you're accessing the entries (in `cin >> label[i]`). Either make this access a `push_back` or initialize the vector to the proper size.

Comment: Okay thanks! I used push_back. It is allowing me to Enter everything, but now when I enter q q to quit, nothing prints.

Comment: There are a couple of variables that are not or incorrectly initialized; `nodes` in `GraphMatrix::List` is not initialized, and `n` is not initialized in the `GraphMatrix`'s constructor. Additionally (unrelated to these problems), note that you're leaking the memory allocated in the  constructor -- anything allocated with `new` needs to be `delete`ed again.

Comment: Hmm I still cannot get the graph to print :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First:

```
vector<string> label;
...
cin >> label[i];
```

Vector has no clue how many items you plan to use, so let's declare it:

```
label.resize(nodes); //now vector populated with 'nodes' default string
```

Second issue with use of `>>` it is intended to work with formatted lines, I assume you need something that responds with pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, that is why use `getline` instead:

```
getline(cin, label[i]);
```

Second: In constructor of graph you don't initialize variable `n`, and `label` hope it should be:

```
    GraphMatrix(const vector<string>&labels):
       n(labels.size()),
       label(labels)
    {
      ...
```

Third: `add_edge` must return true at the end

Forth: In the list method you play dangerous game with mixing names of variables `i` and `j` for inner and outer loops.

After some correction you can find working code there https://ideone.com/3yU9pw (with sample for creation edges [a b] and [c d] )

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot!